# Отсканировать палец и получить уникальный ключ android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, криптография, fingerprint

Всем привет, хочу сделать приложение по хранению паролей и т.п. И хочу прикрутить к нему аутентификацию по отпечатку пальца. Только хочу сделать это достаточно нестандартно.

Из отпечатка пальца мне нужно получить этакий ключ (пускай Int, или String или еще что-нибудь), который был бы уникален для пальца пользователя. (Я понимаю, что с Int'ом могут быть коллизии и т.п. Но я не ожидаю, что к сканеру будут прикладывать пальцы миллиарда китайцев). А затем уже по этому ключу шифровать базу с паролями.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как-то реализовать такой функционал?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это так не работает. Вы можете убедиться, что отпечаток прижатого к сенсору пальца совпадает с отпечатком, добавленным в настройках безопасности, и всё. Если в настройках несколько отпечатков, вы не сможете даже проверить какой из них сработал, а уж тем более не сможете получить fingerprint key.

Если покопаться в исходниках, можно наткнуться на [недокументированный метод](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.java#286). Колбэк `onAuthenticationSucceeded` получает `AuthenticationResult`. В Marshmallow он содержит метод `getFingerprint()`, возвращающий `Fingerprint`, который в свою очередь содержит метод `getName()`, возвращающий присвоенное отпечатку имя. В Nougat у `AuthenticationResult` появился ещё и метод `getUserId()`. Но на сегодняшний день `AuthenticationResult.getFingerprint()` всегда возвращает `null`.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за содержательный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

[Алаверды](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%8B) к ответу @SergeyGornostaev

У Samsung есть (вернее был) собственный API работы с отпечатками - библиотека [PASS SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/pass)

Там есть метод `getRegisteredFingerprintUniqueID()`, который возвращал `Long` с уникальным хэшем отпечатка пальцев.

Работает не всегда (не для всех устройств).

С недавних пор (начиная с версии Android P), как гласит документация:

> We regret to inform you that all devices including upgrade will no longer be providing the Pass SDK from P OS. Applications can use Android Fingerprint API instead of Pass SDK.

Так что закрыта последняя дырка обеспечивавшая получение хэша отпечатка из аппарата.

Comment: Ну вот, к сожалению, мне не годится такой метод, который не на всех устройствах ((